# Can i rewrite URL in MSVS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, url-rewriting

I am using MSVS 2008, C#, ASP.NET project. Right now i can serve any pages i want under http://localhost:3288/ExistingPageInProject.aspx

In MSVS how do i map http://localhost:3288/u/SOME_USER_NAME/media/TITLE-0123 to point to a file/page i have. Such as /u/ExamplePage?name=SOME_USER_NAME&title=TITLE-0123

NOTE: 0123 is the mediaId so the title can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I personally do it is to use 
Application_BeginRequest in 
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication 
and parse the URL with Regex or whatever, and then use 
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath 
to serve the correct page without doing a redirect.

There are also other ways to do it, but that's my preference and its easy to implement.